# Не могу подключиться к базе данных postgresql из java Netbeans

Tags: java, postgresql

Мне надо подключиться к базе данных из Netbeans. Я ввожу все данные которые требуются. Но выдаёт ошибку : "невозможно соединиться с jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bdtest с помощью org.postgresql.Driver (FATAL: database "bdtest" does not exist)". База данных включена. Не понимаю в чём проблема. Ниже скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось очень просто. Я вписал названия сервера вместо названия базы данных. Получилось в поле "База данных" написал вместо bdtest postgres.